# scenario in c++ binary file i/o

Tags: c++, file-io

Having been told by most of the savvy students around campus here, binary file i/o is always faster than formatted i/o. After a bit of googling, i determined that the most efficient way of accomplishing binary i/o was not by streaming directly from the file, each value at a time, but by reading in a large chunk of data, like 4k or 8k chunks, and then parse the data out of that buffer. my question is, say that i used fstream to grab a chunk of data out of a file and stored it into a char array of 8192 bytes. now let's say that it had a header of about 30 bytes, and then all the data after that were like 72 byte stuctures apiece. This would leave 56 bytes of incomplete data at the end which i couldn't read into a structure. How do i handle this to maximize efficiency (yes, using c++ streams, please no whining about c++ streams here, i've heard dozens of arguments on it. This is wholly a question on binary i/o and NOT the efficacy of specific mediums of i/o please). Do i just leave that 56 bytes at the end unused, or do i try to frankenstein together the tail-end and first 16 bytes of the next buffer, or is there still another way to approach this? My question is also, WHY is reading chunks into a buffer like this before parsing, faster? Conversely, if you do not believe this is true, then please explain why if you can. Thanks for your time.

Comment: On any reasonable CPU, the straightforward approach will still be fast enough to keep up with a modern SSD. SSD performance is measured in fractions of a millisecond, CPU performance in fractions of a nanosecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard `iostream` library, it performs buffering automatically.

Comment: So is it still faster to read into one giant buffer and parse vs read it in variable by variable, if iostream buffers automatically?

Comment: Maybe not, but it should be fast enough. The bottlenecks are generally disk access and context switching for system calls.  So it doesn't matter as much whether you use your own buffer or the iostream library's buffer. Are you having a performance problem that needs solving, or is this just a theoretical question?

Comment: entirely theoretical. Been doing a project on my own for learning purposes, and i like to know how to approach a problem before delving into it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Then the first thing you should learn about optimization is don't bother until you run into performance problems. Then use a profiler to determine where the bottlenecks are, and concentrate on them.

Answer (score 0):

First, chunks are overrated. In your case, there is no reason to read 2^N chunks only to re-chunk them some other way.

Second, if you decide to re-chunck, you would do that with a buffer and memory copying.